# Best situations when to use BotFramework Dispatch

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I've been reading the article on setting up BotFramework Dispatch middleware and there are a few things I don't understand. The article is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs

1. Article mentioned to use dispatch when we use multiple LUIS and/or QnA Models. But it seems that as soon as we have 1 of each (LUIS and QnA model) we already need a dispatch. Is there a way to avoid using dispatch if I have just one of each?
2. How does dispatch LUIS get maintained when changes occur in underlying LUIS or QnA models?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Dispatch tool (which is based on LUIS in fact) is being able to dispatch intent between several systems. As soon as you have more than 1 system which can understand intents (whether it is LUIS, QnA Maker or 3rd parties), how would you know which one will be the best for your case?

In a few words, dispatch will group intents for each system into global intents, and so when you call it you will know which systems is the best matching one, then you route your sentence to this best matching system to get the right granularity.

And as you mentioned, to maintain it, there's no secret: it must be updated when you update your underlying LUIS intents/utterances or QnA Maker KB systems

Comment: Right, so everything you said is as I understood it. I was hoping to be wrong because the maintenance aspect of our intents became harder, with 2 separate systems and an additional layer (dispatch LUIS) on top of that.

Comment: Everything can be automated with the help of the APIs and dispatch tool ;-)